# Wrapped Normal Distribution C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, normal-distribution

Does anyone know of anyway to generate a wrapped normal distribution in C++? I have a mean and circular standard deviation and was wondering whether C++ had some function which would generate values from a wrapped normal distribution, similar to their standard normal distribution.

Answer (score 2):

In short, there is no native function in C++ to generate a wrapped normal distribution, but there are several easy ways to calculate it.

## 1. Use Boost

The wrapped normal distribution (WND) is related to the Jacobi theta function [(see here)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapped_normal_distribution). Specifically, it can be formulated in terms of the "third" Jacobi theta function that is available in Boost:

```
    #include <boost/math/special_functions/jacobi_theta.hpp>

    /// Calculate the density function at angle given sigma and mean my.
    double wnd_density(double angle,double my,double sigma)
    {
        double a=(angle-my)/180.0*M_PI;
        double s=sigma/180.0*M_PI;
        return 1.0/(2.0*M_PI)*boost::math::jacobi_theta3tau(0.5*a,(0.5*s*s)/M_PI);
    }
```

## 2. Use iterative formula

Unfortunately Boost does not provide an easy way to implement the *cumulative* WND. Nevertheless, it is rather easy to implement this (and also the WND) using a simple iteration for the third Jacobi theta function. The details are given in [the Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapped_normal_distribution).
The same trick can be used to calculate the indefinite integral that can be derived from the iterative formula by integration per substitution, [see here](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/EllipticTheta3/21/01/01/).

For larger values of sigma both iteration will converge quickly to machine precision (roughly in under 30 iterations for sigma above 20°), smaller values of sigma take around 800 iterations before reaching machine precision. If this is too much you can explicitly set a bigger eps in the given code.

```
    /// Calculate the indefinite integral of the third Jacobi Theta function as described in
    /// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function
    /// Set eps<0 to iterate until machine precision.
    double jacobi_theta3_iterate(double z,double q,double eps=-1.0)
    {
        double th1=1.0,acc=1.0;
        int k=0;
        // This will converge depending on the value of q.
        if(eps<0.0)
        {
            while(th1+acc>th1)
            {
                k++;
                acc=2.0*pow(q,k*k); // an estimate for the accuracy
                th1+=acc*cos(2.0*z*k);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            while(fabs(acc)>=eps)
            {
                k++;
                acc=2.0*pow(q,k*k); // an estimate for the accuracy
                th1+=acc*cos(2.0*z*k);
            }
        }
        return th1;
    }

    /// Calculate the density function at angle given sigma and mean my.
    double wnd_density(double angle,double my,double sigma)
    {
        double a=(angle-my)/180.0*M_PI;
        double s=sigma/180.0*M_PI;
        return 1.0/(2.0*M_PI)*jacobi_theta3_iterate(0.5*a,exp(-0.5*s*s));
    }

    /// Calculate the indefinite integral of the third Jacobi Theta function as described in
    /// https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/EllipticTheta3/21/01/01/
    /// Set eps<0 to iterate until machine precision.
    double jacobi_theta3_integral(double z,double q,double eps=-1.0)
    {
        double th1=z,acc=1.0;
        int k=0;
        // This will converge depending on the value of q.
        if(eps<0.0)
        {
            while(th1+acc>th1)
            {
                k++;
                acc=pow(q,k*k)/k; // an estimate for the accuracy
                th1+=acc*sin(2.0*z*k);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            while(fabs(acc)>eps)
            {
                k++;
                acc=pow(q,k*k)/k; // an estimate for the accuracy
                th1+=acc*sin(2.0*z*k);
            }
        }
        return th1;
    }

    /// Calculate the cumulated density function at angle given sigma and mean my.
    double wnd_cumulated_density(double angle,double my,double sigma)
    {
        double a=(angle-my)/180.0*M_PI;
        double za=(0.0-my)/180.0*M_PI;
        double s=sigma/180.0*M_PI;
        double zero_v=jacobi_theta3_integral(0.5*za,exp(-0.5*s*s));
        return 1.0/M_PI*(jacobi_theta3_integral(0.5*a,exp(-0.5*s*s))-zero_v);
    }
```

You can save a lot of runtime when you use the loop to also iteratively evaluate the iterations of *acc* instead of the costly *pow* function.